# Maven-checktyle-plugin ignores excludes from confiiguration

Tags: maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I have such configuration for checkstyle plugin

`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${test.checkstyle.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <enableRulesSummary>false</enableRulesSummary>
        <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
        <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
        <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
        <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
        <configLocation>${proj_basedir}/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        <suppressionsLocation>${proj_basedir}/checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
        <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
        <excludes>**/generated-sources/**/*.java</excludes>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>6.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- MCHECKSTYLE-156 -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>`

and when I run `mvn compile checkstyle:checkstyle -nsu -Dskip.unit.tests` I see that checkstyle fails for files stored in `generated-sources` folder.
[image]

I run this command from root of my project and in plugin specified in plugins section in pom xml. I also tried to path `exclude` as parameter and get same result. Also updated checkstyle plugin to latest version.